# Does Windows Workflow Foundation raise events in response to state changes?

Tags: workflow-foundation

When a WWF activity completes, is there a trappable event associated with that?  I'd like to catch the event of a state completion.  I've looked, and I can't find a set of events that raise when this happens.

Am I missing it somewhere, or is this not built into WWF?

Answer (score 0):

@Deane, you are able to subscribe to various events during the execution of worflow activities. This is done via Workflow tracking which is a highly configurable event framework that can be subscribed to when executing workflows in WWF 4 (if your using WWF 3.5 I can alter my answer).

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992(v=vs.110).aspx), if you require a basic working example i can assist further.

Comment: Do these events have to built into the activities when they're developed? Or do they exist apart from the activities? I'm working with an existing workflow not developed by me.

Comment: You can configure the Workflow engine to respond to various built in ones. You can also add custom events, but there are all the built in ones you would expect. However you will need to ensure that the application running the workflows is configured to use a tracking participant.